# Workflows - Are there no logs in Salesforce?

Tags: force.com, workflow, email-alert

I'm new to Salesforce having previously used Dynamics CRM. I'm trying to create a workflow to send an email when a new Resource is entered. I'm not getting the email, and there don't appear to be any logs to check for workflows. So I can't tell if it triggered or not. Is this right?

Comment: Can you add in more details as to what have you set the rule criteria and evaluation criteria is? Also make sure the WF is activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check these,

1. create a user (logged in) to view in debug log and search for keyword "workflow"
2. verify you set appropriate trigger action for the workflow
3. verify the criteria for the workflow and your data matches that triggers the workflow
4. check if you have user permission

Comment: You can also set up specific debug logs in Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs. Change the log levels for workflow to "Finest". After triggering an event, check the logs to see the workflow rules that were evaluated, if they were met, and any actions taken.